# Order of operations, BODMAS.

Tags: arithmetic

Given the following expression:

> -7 + 1 - 8 * -10 / 28 - 67 + -54

I resolve it thus:

> -7 + 1 - -80 / 28 - 67 + -54
>
> -7 + 1 - -2 - 67 + -54
>
> -6 - -2 - 67 + -54
>
> -4 - 67 + -54
>
> -71 + -54
>
> **-125**

However various online calculators say the answer is:

### **-124.14285714285714**

What am doing wrong?

Comment: Is it $80/28=2?$

Answer (score 1):

The main issue here is in the second line where you simplify $-80/28$ to equal $-2$. In fact, (-80/28) = (-20/7). So the resulting sum simplifies to $-127 + 20/7$ which does in fact expand to -124.1428...

Fluff aside, I think the real problem here is you're confusing $8$ with $0$ on whatever device you are using. Although if that were true then how come you typed 80 correctly?

Comment: It should be: -80 / 28 = -2

Comment: The point is $\pm\frac {80}{28} \neq \pm 2$

Comment: if it is a troll, its a very good one

Answer (score 0):

> -80 / 28 = **-2.857142857142857**

Not the **-2** stated in question working.
Changing this value now gives the same final result as the online calculators:

> **-124.14285714285714**

Note:
My code was casting the: **-2.857142857142857** to an integer(not a double): **-2**

So losing: **-0.857142857142857** on the conversion.